# I have to check that if I open my project in Internet Explorer Browser, then it opens me texttoindex.component.html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

i want check if my project open into internet explorer then its open first component otherwise other component open on another browser os.

```
 import { Component, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';


import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';


declare var $:JQueryStatic;



var isIE;
var isEdge = !isIE && !!(<any>window).StyleMedia;
if(isEdge==true){


@Component({
  templateUrl: `./texttoindex.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./textcss.css']
})
  export class CrisisCenterHomeComponent implements AfterViewInit{

ngAfterViewInit() {
    }
}

}else{

@Component({
    templateUrl:'./interexplorer.html',
    styleUrls:['./textcss.css']
})

export class CrisisCenterHomeComponent1 implements AfterViewInit{
    ngAfterViewInit(){}
}
}
```

my code check if browser is intenetexploere then open html.
please help me to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to get the curent browser name, you can use `navigator.userAgent`: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

And to switch beetween components, I suggest you to do that in the template of your main component:

```
<div *ngIf="isIE;then crisisCenterHome else crisisCenterHome1"></div>
<ng-template #crisisCenterHome>
  <app-crisis-center-home></app-crisis-center-home>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #crisisCenterHome1>
  <app-crisis-center-home-one></app-crisis-center-home-one>
</ng-template>
```

Note that isIE must be into your main component class.

Comment: Hello @Florian D thank you for response now i implement this in my project.